# Java String Containing Spaces

Tags: java

I want to display same string accessed from user through console using Scanner class which contains white spaces?

ex..

input string
                "Welcome to Java"
output string
                "Welcome to Java"

using java `System.out.println();`

I don't want to use nextLine() method.

please anyone help me out to resolve this problem

thanks for reading

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    Double d = scan.nextDouble();
    String s = scan.next();
    System.out.println("String: " + s);
    System.out.println("Double: " + d);
    System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    scan.close();
}
```

}

output:

```
20
34.45
Welcome to Java
String: Welcome
Double: 34.45
Int: 20
```

Comment: Why you dont want to use nextLine ?

Comment: It looks as an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/340236)

Comment: The problem appears to be that you don't want to use nextLine(). How can we help you overcome this want?

Comment: Hint: when you know about scanner, maybe you *want* to read all of the documentation for that class? So maybe you get other ideas for things that you want to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use `java.util.Scanner.next()` method.

see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())

> **next()**
>   Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = sc.next();
System.out.println(str);
```

---

There are also plenty of other options available if you're willing to switch from `Scanner` class. One possible option is using `java.io.BufferedReader` class.

```
BufferedReader bi = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String str = bi.readLine();
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following bit will do what you want it to:

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = myScanner.next();
System.out.println(name);
```

It uses the [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) method of the scanner class.

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code snippet:

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".*", 0);
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: myScanner is object/reference
 of which class